# Global session + authentication, multiple contexts in Jetty

Tags: java, jetty

I seem to be running into an odd problem with scoped handlers in Jetty 7. What I want to achieve is to have a single authentication page (and a single session), which protects multiple `WebAppContext`s. The sensible solution seemed to me to put all the webapps in a `ContextHandlerCollection`, and to wrap this in a `SecurityHandler` and `SessionHandler`. However, looking at the Jetty code, it seems to me that this can never work propery. The following code demonstrates the core problem:

```
Server server = new Server(8000);

SimpleServlet h1 = new SimpleServlet("Servlet 1");
SimpleServlet h2 = new SimpleServlet("Servlet 2");

ServletContextHandler c1 = new ServletContextHandler();
ServletContextHandler c2 = new ServletContextHandler();

c1.addServlet(new ServletHolder(h1), "/");
c2.addServlet(new ServletHolder(h2), "/");

c1.setContextPath("/context1");
c2.setContextPath("/context2");

ContextHandlerCollection chc = new ContextHandlerCollection();
chc.setHandlers(new Handler[]{c1, c2});

SessionHandler sh = new SessionHandler();
sh.setHandler(chc);

server.setHandler(sh);
```

When a request comes in, this ends up in `handle` in the `SessionHandler`. Here, `doScope` is called, since the session handler is the outermost scope. The problem is that the `ContextHandlerCollection` is not a scoped handler, so `nextScope` is set to the first `ServletContextHandler`! There is no way that `doScope` will ever be called on the second `ServletContextHandler`.

But, even that first servlet is not reachable. `doScope` in the `ServletHandler` is called, and ends up calling `doHandle` on the outer scope (the session handler) with `target` set to `/`. But: the `ContextHandlerCollection` does not know of a context called `/`, so the result is a 404.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am trying to construct the same "global session" topology.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, I guess this should work :

```
Server server = new Server(8000);

SimpleServlet h1 = new SimpleServlet("Servlet 1");
SimpleServlet h2 = new SimpleServlet("Servlet 2");

ServletContextHandler c = new ServletContextHandler();
c.setContextPath("/");
c.addServlet(new ServletHolder(h1), "/context1");
c.addServlet(new ServletHolder(h2), "/context2");

SessionHandler sh = new SessionHandler();
sh.setHandler(c);

server.setHandler(sh);
```

But I guess you figured it out yourself by the time...

Bye